# How to take out only 1 word from a string in Lua

Tags: string, lua, split, lua-patterns

I know **how to split the whole string** and **put it in a table** but **I need to take out only the first word** and then the rest of the string needs to stay the same.

I tried to do something on this but I have no idea:

```
words = {}
for word in s:gmatch("%w+") do table.insert(words,word) end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match one word, you should use `string.match` instead of `string.gmatch`:

```
local words = {}
words[1], words[2] = s:match("(%w+)(.+)")
```

`words[1]` contains the first word, the `words[2]` contains the rest.

Comment: the string is "Cookie hello there sir" and it gives me the error "attempt to index ? ( a nil value)

Comment: @user3319763 Check http://ideone.com/fao4Q8 to see what's the difference. Perhaps `words` is supposed to be global in your program. I modified it to `local` as a habit.

Answer (score 0):

Yu Hao's solution has an edge case that breaks: if 's' is itself just a single word it will return that word w/o the last character to words[1] and the last character to words[2].

Here's a workaround I made that will catch this edge case properly:

```lua
local words = {}
words[1], words[2] = s:match("(%w+)(%W+)")
if words[1] == nil then words[1] = s end
```

Changed `.+` to be `\W+` (so only non-word characters can come between words).  This might result in no match at all (if the string is empty or has only one word) so I check and fix that case.

There might be a better way that gets it all in a single match pattern, but I just wanted to offer this up for a workaround if anyone hits this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Ollie's solution seemed a bit overkill.

If you want to handle situations where the string may contain 1 or more words then you just need to change the 2nd capture from ".+" to ".*".

```
s:match("(%w+)(.*)")
```